# New Line in Facebook message using JS SDK

Tags: facebook-javascript-sdk

I am using Facebook Javascript SDK to post on user's wall. In the description I want to show multi-line text. I tried different tags like br or div. I even tried "\r\n" but nothing seems to work. Is there a standard solution for it?